# How to draw pie chart in Cytoscape(or any JavaScript) tree

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape-web, cytoscape, cytoscape.js

- I have use Cytoscape  [javascript](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) to draw a Tree.
- The problem is I want to display many of value in a node, so we decide to draw the pie chart instead of it's original circle to represent many value. But I don't know how to draw pie chart over a node.
- I have found this  [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/pie/search_engine_share/)
- Please tell me how to draw this pie chart over another javascript(Cytoscape).

**or any alternative solution**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a special visual style value for you to do this. I've made a ticket to track the feature. There will probably be time in the next few weeks to add this, or I could point you to the relevant code so you can make the changes and a pull request. https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/283

Comment: As I tell before, my point is to separate one node in many piece like pie chart
(May be 1 to 4 data set for each node)

Please tell me if there is anyway to do that. 
(Just separate a node to be many piece, or draw half(or quarter) of node with the other to make it look lie pie chart ?)